# How to keep hash tag symbol when saving file using Numpy?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, csv, data-cleaning

I am cleaning some text data from unwanted strings. My text data include # in the first line, and when I save the file it will be gone cause it is not readable by Python.

Text example:

```
@peak,+ID,#val
1,nopeak
2,nopeak
3,peak
4,nopeak

@category,+ID,#val
1,high
2,low
3,high
4,high
```

What I have done to remove unwanted strings in the lines:

```
data1 = np.genfromtxt('text.b', dtype=str, delimiter="\t")

idxList = [1,2]

for p,q in enumerate(idxList):
    OutArr1 = []
    RemoveStr = str(q)
    for i,j in enumerate(data1):
        if j[:4] != RemoveStr: OutArr1.append(str(j))   
    OutArr2 = np.asarray(OutArr1, dtype=np.str)
    np.savetxt('sample_' + str(q) + '.txt', OutArr2, fmt='%s')
```

Current output:

```
@peak,+ID,
3,peak
4,nopeak

@category,+ID,
3,high
4,high
```

How do I manage to keep the hash tag symbol (#val) in every first line?

Comment: That's interpreted as a comment marker.

Comment: Check the `comments` argument to [`np.genfromtxt`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.genfromtxt.html)

Comment: Why are you using numpy for this? Can you share more of your program and data? This is probably a job for the csv module or Pandas. Also, variable and function names should follow the `lower_case_with_underscores` style.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'#' is used as a comment starter with the default config of `genfromtxt`. Simply replace by:

```
data1 = np.genfromtxt('text.b', dtype=str, delimiter="\t", comments=None)
```